# Can I use same mapedBy name in a class?

Tags: hibernate, mapping, java-ee-7

I'm getting this error but I'm not sure if it is because of the name of mappedBy is the same in to properties

**Error**

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Collection, at table: a_escalaPregunta, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(valoracioItems)]
```

Class EscalaPregunta

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "a_escalaPregunta")
public class EscalaPregunta extends BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(length = 255)
    private String pregunta;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "pregunta", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Collection<EscalaResposta> respostes;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "pregunta", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private Collection<ValoracioItem> valoracioItems;

    @Id
    public Long getId(){
       return id;
    }
```

Class EscalaResposta

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "a_escalaResposta")
public class EscalaResposta extends BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "idEscalaPregunta", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    private EscalaPregunta pregunta;
```

Class ValoracioItem

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_valoracioitem")
public class ValoracioItem extends BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "idEscalaPregunta", nullable = false)
    private EscalaPregunta pregunta;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the annotation @Id was repeted in the property and the getter method.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed following attribute in ValoracioItem  entity

```
referencedColumnName = "id"
```

It should be someting like this

```
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "idEscalaPregunta", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    private EscalaPregunta pregunta;
```

Comment: No luck, I get the same error. Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Collection, at table: a_escalaPregunta, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(valoracioItems)]"},